# Laravel frontend and backend with different multilanguage

Tags: laravel, multilingual, setlocale

In Laravel at the same time i need have different language/locale in site frontend and backend(administration). Frontend need 4 languages(en,de,fr,it), backend need 3 languages(en,lt,es).
Example: In browser i have two open tabs - 1 tab frontend (lang: de), 2 tab backend (lang: en). How to do it ? with setLocale? or i need different array for example backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can easily handle this is by creating two `BaseController` classes for your frontend and backend controllers.

You can then set different languages for your frontend and backend from the right `BaseController` constructor using `App::setLocale` method.

Example:

```php
<?php

class FrontendBaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        App::setLocale(Session::get('frontend-locale'));
    }
}


class BackendBaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        App::setLocale(Session::get('backend-locale'));
    }
}

class HomeController extends FrontendBaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}

class BackendDashboardController extends BackendBaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}
```

In the above example, I'm retrieving the current locale from the session.
You can put your language files in the `app/lang` folder. I will suggest you to have separate folders for your frontend and backend language files.

Example folder structure:

```php
/app
    /lang
        /en
            backend/
                dashboard.php

            frontend/
                home.php

        /de
            backend/
                dashboard.php

            frontend/
                home.php
```

Sample content of `app/lang/en/backend/dashboard.php`:

```php
<?php
return array(
    'welcome' => 'Welcome to Backend!'
);
```

You can output the value of `welcome` key for example with
`echo Lang::get('backend/dashboard.welcome');`.

I hope you got the idea. For more details, feel free to check out the [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/localization#introduction).

Comment: Ok. But where and how to set frontend and backend arrays with languages?

Comment: @Mantoze I added some more details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening two different tabs in the same browser, perhaps you should consider opening two different browser sessions, to avoid that the backend- and frontend-sessions with different language settings overwrite each other.